# location of temp jars in OSX

Tags: java, openejb

I am using osX (Yosemite). I could not find and delete jars made by openejb and is causing a lot of problems. Can someone point out where are these temp ejb jars stored. Its not in Library/cache/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the required information from console of the ejb server. For me the location was /private/var/folders/7j/ypktqd5d6zn1kw6l8b8841r0y7ttb_/T/
I could delete the old oejb files and get stuff done.